# In X11 is it possible to instruct the client to launch a process in a reduced color palette?

Tags: x11

**Scenario:**

1. I work on my Macbook running X11 Quartz
2. I log into a remote server running CentOS via X11 forwarding over ssh from my Macbook
3. I wish to launch a web browser from the server but due to the reduced bandwidth I would like to launch it using a 256 color pallet

Is that possible?

Comment: The application has to know how to do it (see [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19620-01/805-3921/6j3nm4qiu/index.html) for insight)).

Answer (score 1):

No. In the X11 protocol it's the server which manages bit depth.

If you want something like that, please use VNC.

Comment: That's incorrect.  Try looking for how to specify a *visual*.

Comment: I've tried searching for a "visual" - found absolutely nothing. Meanwhile I've found out that most of my graphical applications don't even run when the X11 server (Xephyr) depth is set to 8. Even if this "visual" exists, I'm sure VNC does a better job of converting true colors to 8 bit.